# Trigger/Publish pattern without Subject

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

This one keeps me up at night. Say I have a simple interface like this:

```
public interface INotifier
{
    IObservable<string> Messages { get; }
    void SendMessage(string message);
}
```

How could I implement this interface without using a `Subject<string>` or equivalent stateful construct internally?

I don't mean for this to be a dogmatic debate, more of a thought experiment. If this were a real problem, I wouldn't think twice about using a subject to do this. I was just curious if anybody had an approach to it that I had not considered that they could share and just maybe broaden our collective outlook.

Comment: I assume `SendMessage` should pipe a message into the `Messages` observable?

Comment: That's the idea, yes. Maybe a little oversimplified, but I was trying to make my idea clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the definition of `ISubject<T>` (simplified slightly):

```
interface ISubject<T> : IObserver<T>, IObservable<T>
{
    void OnValue(T value);
    void OnError(Exception error);
    void OnCompleted();
    IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer);
}
```

Now look at a conceptually-equivalent definition of your `INotifier`:

```
interface INotifier : IObservable<string>
{
    IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<string> observer);
    void OnValue(string value);
}
```

Do you see the problem? Your `INotifier` describes exactly the concept of a subject, minus `OnError` and `OnCompleted`. Although it isn't immediately obvious, your question can be reduced to the question: "How could I implement a subject without a subject?"

At some point, every notification observed by a subscriber to an observable must have come from somewhere. If that ultimate source is "cold," you shouldn't need subjects anywhere. If that ultimate source is "hot," meaning the values are pushed at you from outside your program, but not as an `IObservable<T>`, you must use a subject. It's inevitable. In those cases, the goal is to place the subject directly at that ultimate source.

Comment: I completely agree. I was just trying to approach this from the Lee Campbell school of thought where subjects are by definition stateful and kind of anti-functional because suddenly you have this state object to complicate things. I felt like maybe there was some way to exploit Observable.Create() to achieve it without the subject acting as a pipe in-between that I just wasn't seeing.

Comment: @MojoFilter If you have something like an MVC Controller Action method, and you want calls to it to be represented as an `IObservable<HttpRequest>`, the only way you can do that is by using a subject. The "avoid subjects when they aren't *needed*" mantra is really good advice - it's just that it is sometimes presented as "never, ever use subjects because they are for bad programmers." That isn't true. There are places where you must use a subject.

Comment: Dave Sexton has a somewhat abstract but thorough blog about [when to use subjects](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx). There is one specific case where Subjects are basically the only choice you have, but just having a hot, non-IObservable source isn't enough. Events and callbacks are two hot, non IObservable sources that can easily be converted to Observables without using Subjects. In your case, it looks like a Subject is what you want. You could just pass a Subject around, but IMO that's far worse than wrapping one.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Timothy Shields here. You are trying to implement `ISubject` without using a subject. I also understand that you have simplified the interface to keep the question focused (which is appreciated). However in this case I think one would need to step back and look at the layering/design of the system to understand *why* you have a class that appears to be an event broker. Most times when I see a subject being used it is either valid (1% of the time), or it is actually the way the system is being structured that is issue that needs to be solved.